# Applying a filter at one point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a set of extremely large filters (total of 9015, each 910 x 910) that I'd like to apply to some specific points in an image (< 10000). Basically, the reason for the very large size of these filters is that each filter is meant to be applied to only one point, yet still take into account the entirety of the image.  The math behind what I'd like to do (application of filters / convolution) is quite simple (that is, element-wise multiply the image by the filter, and then element-wise sum in each dimension.) The following is an implementation I wrote in python and numpy (where `...` indicates some area in memory to store the result):

```
for q in range(3): # A variable to iterate through the color channels, given that the filters are only 2 dimensional
    for i in range (len(filters)):
            ... = np.floor(np.sum(np.sum(filters[:,:,i] * img[:,:,q], axis = 1), axis = 0) + 0.5)
# Note that filters[:,:,i] selects the correct filter for the current given point
```

But this takes an extremely long time on my pretty powerful machine (on the order of 280 seconds.) Given that is the case, I attempted to use library functions to hopefully speed things up (because I assume that they are highly optimized), but something like (with the same notes as above reapplied here)

```
for q in range(3):
        for i in range (len(filters)):
            ... = scipy.ndimage.convolve(img[:,:,q], filters[:,:,i]))
```

doesn't help much. (I couldn't even time it. This is almost certainly because the number of calculations to be done here is *much* higher, because it calculates the cell values at each point in the image with an extremely large filter.) At this point, I am looking for ways to speed this up, and I still believe that a library function is the right way to go. If there was a function that did convolution at one point, or as I referred to it in the title, an application of a filter at one point, I could loop through the fewer points of interest (rather than the whole image), calling this library function at each of these points. Or is there some function that takes in a set of indices to run convolution on? Or maybe there is a way to reshape the data so that the library convolution functions only run at certain points?

Are there any functions in python, numpy, scipy etc. that have this functionality?

Comment: Could you add mcve - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag, as this question is completely written in and for Python, with MATLAB shoehorned at the end. If you want to ask a similar question for MATLAB, please rewrite the question accordingly, as it is too broad and/or lacking a [mcve] for that language.

Comment: @Divakar I updates to hopefully better fur the MCVE guidelines. It is sufficient now?

Comment: @Acoop a MCVE is code that you can copy, paste, and it would run/reproduce the issue. Yours does not do that

Comment: I can't share the filters as they are private, and also several gigabytes. How might I create something that is copy-pasteable where the issues lies in inefficiency, but where I can't share the thing which makes it inefficient?

Comment: @Acoop You could set up smaller, more general filters, small artificial inputs, etc. Actually, you want to get rid of the costly loop approach in favor of some kind "vectorized" approach, don't you? Therefore, it's not necessary to kill everybody's machines with your original stuff, but a minimal example is actually needed to see, what you're doing right now, and how to improve your current approach.

Comment: One small, obvious improvement is to swap the two loops. That way you only read the filter data from main memory into the cache once. You might also consider applying the dot product to vectorized image and filter. But in general this is a lot of computation and therefore will take a lot of time.